# AWS CloudFront failover to backup bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, failover

I setup [this website (`www.s3post.cf`)](http://www.s3post.cf/) which uses a `Node.js` server to get [this json file](http://d1dkpjfts1swxw.cloudfront.net/s3posts.json.gz) from `CloudFront` and display its content on the site.

The Cloudfront distribution uses this *US EAST (N. Virginia) bucket* (`cloudfront.s3post.cf`) as the origin. I will be creating a new bucket in *US WEST (N. California)* and enable cross-replication between the two buckets.

What I want to do is, when the *US EAST* bucket becomes unavailable, I need CloudFront to point to the backup bucket in *US WEST*. So basically an origin failover. How would I go about doing this?

I realize that I can code my application to failover to the backup bucket when the file becomes unavailable, but is there a way to get CloudFront to use another origin instead?

Also, is there a better way of doing this than what I have in mind with minimal downtime? I was able to use `Route 53` for failover previously, but that was for a website being hosted statically on `S3` without a backend server like in the current scenario.

*P.S. - This is a test website that I setup to test failover scenarios.*